# How to process a file in R and inspect R session interactively after?

Tags: r

I'd like to process a file in R and then get access to an interactive session after the file is processed.

It seems like one way to do it would be to combine the `-f` flag with the `--interactive` argument like:

```
`r -f file.R --interactive`
```

But the r console exits after processing the file.

Comment: why don't you just open R Session and run `source` command

Comment: I'll do that. Just started learning R today, so I wasn't sure what I should do. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open R session and use

```
setwd("<path.to.file>")
source("file.R")
```